# Slickr Flickr doesn't show Flickr captions

Tags: wordpress, flickr

We have been prepping a Wordpress site to use the Slickr Flickr plug-in (non-paid version). We are using a thumbnail layout with captions on certain pages. Everything was working great...

However, recently, the captions stopped being displayed, but they are still in Flickr.

We don't believe we have changed anything that should have caused the captions to disappear and the settings still have the captions on.

Anyone experience this too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source of your [page](http://1amsf.com/demo/?page_id=4736#page-top) and the titles are there in fact.

This is a snippet which shows the caption in the title attribute of the img.

```
<a href="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6224/6336088614_8642e4331e.jpg"><img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6224/6336088614_8642e4331e_s.jpg" alt="" title="&quot;Violet-haired TQ&quot; by Bubblegumking" /></a>
```

Given that neither Slickr Flickr or the Galleria code have changed, have you added any other plugin or script that may be changing links?